# Node.js require works but attribute isn't defined

Tags: node.js

**Problem:**

I include a .js-file with require to get access to the functions.

The file I'm requiring looks something like this:

```
MyFile = {

f1: function(value) {
    // some code
},

f2: function(value) {
    // some code
}, 

// and so one....
```

Code snipped how I call my function f1:

```
expr = MyFile.f1('Hello');
```

Interesting about this is that it doesn't work in my case. The require part works fine. I tested if this may be the problem but it wasn't. My co-woker who has the same code can run it witout a problem, however I receive the following message:

> ReferenceError: MyFile not defined.

Can someone explain me what could cause this problem?

**Solution:**

Instead of `require` I'm using `module.expoerts` now and it works fine.

Here you can see what I canged:

`MyFile = {` changed to `module.exports = {`

`require('./MyFile.js');` assinged to a attribute e.g `var MyFile = require('./MyFile.js');`

Comment: I'll need to see how you are requiring your file

Comment: Like this: `require('./MyFile.js')`. The two files are in the same folder. I tried to require it without the ./ and he couldn't find the module. It proved me that the module is found.

Comment: Are you doing module.exports = MyFile in your MyFile script at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you run your code in 'strict mode', and your coworker does not, so he does not get the reference error.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyFile = {

f1: function(value) {
    // some code
},

f2: function(value) {
    // some code
}, 

// and so one....
module.exports = MyFile;
```

And

```
const MyFile = require('./MyFile.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Code whatever you want to export like this

```
   exports.MyFile = {

    f1: function (value) {
        // some code
    },

    f2: function (value) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

save it as **moduleFile.js**

then call it like this

```
let obj= require('./moduleFile');
// Use Object MyFile from moduleFile like this

obj.MyFile.f1('Hello');
```

- **Note 1**: Don't use confusing names like *myfile* everywhere.
- **Note 2**: Don't *.js* extension while importing.
- **Note 3**: You can also export function from there without using an object but normally this is not recommeded.