# Node.js - Modify node_module content

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Here is the deal, I have downloaded a node module. But I had to modify the code of the library.

Now I want to upload my code to `heroku`, but `heroku` will install the dependencies of the `package.json` file, and the code of the library will be unchanged.

So is there a way to put that module outside of the node_modules folder?

The only references of the library is in the `package.json` file.
And in the program, the library is accessed by one file.

```
var containerVar = require('modified_module');
```

Comment: Why not manually download and move it outside of `node_modules`? And commit it with the code

Comment: And how will my code call it? I mean the require command

Comment: `var containerVar = require('path/to/modified/module')`. If you don't want to use relative paths then check here https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Comment: @user1584421 Check this out. an answer I gave a few days ago.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057049/node-js-require-works-but-attribute-isnt-defined/52058095#52058095)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way would be to write your own module. So, take the module that you need, change its content as you already done and in its package.json give it your new custom name. You can even publish it on npm. You only need to sign up to npm. Than you can call in your projects package.json module that you have published and your problem is solved.

Comment: Isn't it unethical to publish it as my own package? I mean i only made some minor changes to an existing package, to suit my needs.

Comment: You can add in description in package.json that it is a module for special/individual need. Add url to the repo of original module and explain what and why you have changed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can host your modified (local) package on Github and install the package from there.

For example, if I modified redis module, I can upload the modified package on to Github and tell my app to install from Github as opposed to installing from NPM.

The dependency part of my package.json file would look like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "redis-modified": "github:username/redis-modified",
}
```

You can use it like any regular module

```
var redis = require("redis-modified");
```

In summary, you would be creating a new version of the package and hosting it.